# Under Cabinet Lighting (Kitchen) - Wire too Short

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have installed a new LED fixture under the cabinet in the kitchen (see picture below). I want the fixture installed at the front of the cabinet as shown in the picture below. The wiring is too short.

Question: How can I fix this is a manner that meets or exceeds the NEC without it looking like a hack-job.

## Background

Here are some ideas I have researched.

### Legrand Wiremold

I have consider using something like Legrand Wiremold because it is shallow and seems to hide well under the cabinet. (See pictures below). But I cannot figure out how to transition from the Wiremold to the fixture. And I cannot figure out how transition from the wall to the Wiremold raceway.

### PVC

I have consider using the PVC 1/2", but the boxes are too deep. I like that PVC has smooth surfaces for easy cleaning when it gets dusty.

### Armored Cable

I have considered using armored cable, but seems hard to clean when it collects dust. I believe I would install a shallow box from where the NM cable exits the wall and then use armored cable from the box to the fixture.

## Pictures

This is a picture of the fixture installed under the cabinet. As you can see, the wiring is too short.
[image]

This is the LED light that I installed.

> GE 34289 LED Under Cabinet Fixture, Direct Wire, 1100 Lumens, 97 CRI, Light Color Selection, On/Off Switch, in-Wall Dimmer Compatible, Steel Housing, 24 Inch, White [image]

### Legrand Wiremold:

Raceway Combination Connector (Transition from NM-Cable into the Raceway

[image]

Shallow Switch and Receptacle Box (as junction box)

[image]

Comment: The bare wires there are completely unacceptable to be exposed.  The cable must enter a junction box while still in a sheath, and really should enter a junction box instantly, with no exposed cable.

Answer (score 2):

Use wiremold, put a box at the wall entry with a hole to match where the cable comes out of the wall, and a box at the fixture, also with holes lining up.

Or, use EMT (smooth and easy to clean) which should be do-able with a fitting at the fixture and a box at the wall.

Comment: EMT metal conduit is the best answer if the light has a "standard knockout" entrance.  Unlike Wiremold it nicely fits standard knockouts.  Unlike PVC it's less bulky, yet still smooth to clean unlike flex. It's actually nicer to work with once you get used to it.  Of course you won't be working with it long enough for its appeal to grow.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem and solved it with a wiremold box. Here is a picture after installation.
[image]